# OnCheckedChange doesnt fire server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I know there is many questions about this and i have looked at the answers but nothing works for me when i test the answers they got.

My problem is that i can´t reach the method on server side when the checkbox is checked or unchecked. Nothing happens.

Here is my code:

The repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTimeWeekTable" OnItemDataBound="rptrptTimeWeekTable_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptTimeWeekTable_ItemCommand" runat="server">
```

The checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chBoxSum" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnCheckedChanged="chBoxSum_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void chBoxSum_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chBox = (CheckBox)sender;

    int rowIndex = ((RepeaterItem)chBox.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;

    CheckBox chBoxMon = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxMonday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxTue = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxTuesday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxWed = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxWednesday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxThu = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxThursday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxFri = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxFriday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxSat = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxSaturday") as CheckBox;
    CheckBox chBoxSun = rptTimeWeekTable.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("chBoxSunday") as CheckBox;

    if (chBox.Checked == true)
    {
        chBoxMon.Checked = true;
        chBoxTue.Checked = true;
        chBoxWed.Checked = true;
        chBoxThu.Checked = true;
        chBoxFri.Checked = true;
        chBoxSat.Checked = true;
        chBoxSun.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chBoxMon.Checked = false;
        chBoxTue.Checked = false;
        chBoxWed.Checked = false;
        chBoxThu.Checked = false;
        chBoxFri.Checked = false;
        chBoxSat.Checked = false;
        chBoxSun.Checked = false;
    }

}

    protected void rptTimeWeekTable_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Is it only *OnCheckedChanged* not working? Can you try some other checkbox event just to make sure issue is not specific to the event? Also are did you try with break point in code behind handler, because it may also be possible that your logic did not work, hence you concluded that.

Comment: I have tried different events on all my checkboxes but nothing works. I have tried with breakpoints both in itemcommand and protected void  chBoxSum_CheckedChanged. The breakpoint doesnt "fire"

Comment: I have tested to have a checkbox outside the repeater but it doesnt fire the oncheckedchange event. Can i lost the connection to serverside in some way?

Comment: Looks like something else is going on. Perhaps some script error (which may not be even related to this) on page prevents it from working. Quite possible! Open up developer tools in browser (F12) and check what response you get in web console when you click check box.

Comment: Also check if there is a post to the server at all fired in the same developer tools(network tab).

Comment: Ok, i dont know what to look for in developer tools. I use Firefox. Can you help me where i should look?

Comment: There is no post that fires in the net tab. But when i click on a button in the same row there is a post.

Comment: Should i write some code in itemcommand?